# Data Structure for Floorplan with Moveable Walls

Tags: data-structures

I am currently reading through the paper ["Computer-Generated Residential Building Layouts" by Paul Merrell, Eric Schkufza and Vladlen Koltun](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Vladlen-Koltun/publication/256663544_Computer-Generated_Residential_Building_Layouts/links/0deec523931bd0de3d000000/Computer-Generated-Residential-Building-Layouts.pdf?origin=publication_detail). In this paper, they create and optimize floorplans by exploring the space of possible floorplans through a set of modifying operations. One of these operations is the sliding of a wall.

When a wall is slid, it is first split at some point along that wall. This point may be at one of the ends of the wall or it may be in the middle of the wall. If it is at one of the ends, the wall stays in one piece. If it is in the middle, this results in two walls, one of which is slid. Sliding means to move the wall some distance forwards, keeping the rooms enclosed through the creation of new walls and modification of existing walls.

[image: Example of wall sliding taken from the paper]

How would one go about implementing a representation of a floorplan which can facilitate such operations?

Comment: Why not use a standard DCEL to represent it (similarly to how polygons are represented)?

Comment: @nirshahar That would actually work very well. I have only ever worked with a DCEL long ago in some computer graphics class and it didn't even occur to me that I could use it here. That would make most of this quite easy.